# Differentiating an Entity in an ER diagram

Tags: database, entity, entity-relationship

Title might not be what it needs to be. Give me a suggestion to change it if I got it wrong. I have to do and ER diagram for a assignment. My employees are either cooks or waiters. The cooks get a fixed salary but the waiters are paid per hour.
How do I differentiate a cook from a waiter in the diagram?

Comment: You can define an entity called `EmployeeTypes` which will contains Cook and Waiter value, it will be a foreign key inside table `Employees` and it will play the role of a `Discriminator` and you can add too more tables `Cooks` and `Waiters` which they are child to the `Employees` table to store their specific data and in the table `Employees` you can store the common fields

Answer (score 0):

There are many options...

- A single Entity with employment type, hourly and fixed salary in separate fields or with salary and salary type (hourly / fixed) fields
- Two separate Entities (cooks, waiters) with the corresponding fields
- One Entity for Employees, separate entities for "Hourly wage" and "Fixed salary" with optional 1:1 relationships

If this is an assignment, you are probably expected to use a new concept that was introduced recently O:)